# the definition of decoder layer in autoencoder model for mnist case

Tags: deep-learning, keras, mnist

I am trying to follow the example given in [this blog](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) to build the autoencoder model.

```
input_img = Input(shape=(784,))
encoded = Dense(128, activation='relu')(input_img)
encoded = Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded)
encoded = Dense(32, activation='relu')(encoded)
decoded = Dense(64, activation='relu')(encoded)
decoded = Dense(128, activation='relu')(decoded)
decoded = Dense(784, activation='sigmoid')(decoded)

# this model maps an input to its reconstruction
autoencoder = Model(input=input_img, output=decoded)

encoded_input = Input(shape=(encoding_dim,))
decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1]
decoder = Model(input=encoded_input, output=decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

The modification I made is `decoder = Model(input=encoded_input, output=decoded)`, which was written as `decoder = Model(input=encoded_input, output=decoder_layer(encoded_input))` in the original post. The previous version works for single hidden layers. That is why I made the above modification. However, compiling the above model gives the following error message. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "train.py", line 37, in <module>
 decoder = Model(input=encoded_input, output=decoded)
 File "tfw/lib/python3.4/site-packages/Keras-1.0.3-py3.4.egg/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1713, in __init__
str(layers_with_complete_input))
Exception: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, 784), dtype=float32) at layer "input_1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and managed to put together a messy but effective solution. Change the line where you define the decoder to this:

```
decoder = Model(input=encoded_input, output=autoencoder.layers[6](autoencoder.layers[5](autoencoder.layers[4](encoded_input))))
```

The error that you saw indicated that there was a disconnected graph.  In this case, the input tensor, defined as `encoded_input`, was being fed directly to the final output tensor, defined as the final decoded layer (the dense layer with 784 dimensions).  The intermediate tensors (the dense layers with 64 and 128 dimensions) were skipped over.  My solution nests those layers so that each serves as the input for the next, and the innermost tensor has the `encoded_input` as the input.